# Multiple variables from single line in Python?

Tags: python, input

I'm trying to figure out how have something like "Enter an expression: " take in 3 variables: the first int, the character of the operation, and the second int. This is very easy in C++ with just cin >> num1 >> operation >> num2.

So far, per others' questions, I've tried taking in a list and splitting it. This works, except for integers with more than 1 digit. I'm doing something like this:

```
list1=raw_input()
list1.split()
print list1
num1=list1[0]
plus=list1[1]
num2=list1[2]
print num1, plus, num2
```

For example, entering 10+3 would output 1 0 +
I feel like there's a simple fix here, but I don't know it. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest using regex for this case, for example:

```
 re_exp = re.compile(r'\s*(\d+)\s*([^\d\s])+\s*(\d+)')
 expr = raw_input()
 match = re_exp.match(expr)
 if match:
     num1, oper, num2 = match.groups()
     print num1, oper, num2
```

With `split`, you can parse `10 + 1` but it will be harder to do with `10+1` (without spaces), or to handle both cases.

Comment: yeah, i just realized that. thanks! It's just for me (the program) so I don't need to deal with lack of spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Strings are immutable, so you need to capture the result of `list1.split()` somewhere. But it won't help you, since that won't do what you want. Use a parser, possibly using [Python's language services](http://docs.python.org/library/language.html).

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
list1 = raw_input()
for x in list1.split():
    print x,
```

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams there, fixed it.

Comment: The `IndexError` is gone, but this still won't do what the asker wants.

Answer (score 0):

```
#You should write like this
list1 = raw_input()
a=list1.split()
num1=a[0]
plus=a[1]
num2=a[2]
print num1, plus, num2
```

Comment: Hey, welcome to SO. Would be great if you could explain your code and give examples why  op "should write like this".